# Regex, finding all words that end with a specific letter

Tags: linux, regular-expression

I am self-learning regex so that I can manage my Linux files a lot better for work but I am having trouble finding a word that ends with a specified letter.

I know how to find words that begin with a letter using:

```
grep -o '\bs\w*' File.txt
```

I've been trying to add $ so it can do what I am looking for, though I have had no success.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to manage files you probably need to put REs to one side for a short while and first learn about shell globs. These are far easier for most use cases and are (mostly) what the shells use for their pattern matching.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the pointer, I will look into shell globs.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out using:

```
grep -o '\w*s\b' File.txt
```

If anyone has a similar/better method with the same result please enlighten me.

Comment: `\w` and `\b` are GNU extensions.